# binding this keyword on anonymous & async function

Tags: javascript, mongodb, asynchronous, parse-platform, promise

In JavaScript I am looking for a way to use bind() on an anonymous and async function.

Example:

```
exports.foo = function () {};

exports.foo.prototype = {
  load : function(id) {
    var query = new Parse.Query("SomeObject");
    query.get(id).then(function(object) {
      this.object = object; // this is the wrong this
    });
  }
};
```

I got this working by making the functions non-anonymous, but I think it makes my code look ugly. Especially after having 4 different anonymous functions in a row.

```
exports.foo = function () {};

exports.foo.prototype = {
  load : function(id) {

    function _load(object) {
      this.object = object;
    }
    var _loadThis = _load.bind(this);

    var query = new Parse.Query("SomeObject");
    query.get(id).then(_loadThis);
  }
};
```

Is there a better way?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well it's not necessarily "better", but you can call `.bind()` directly after the closing brace of your function instantiation expression:

```
query.get(id).then(function(object) {
  this.object = object; // this is the wrong this
}.bind(this));
```

A function instantiation expression gives you a function object reference, so putting a `.` after it and calling `bind` makes sense.  What gets passed to the `.then` function, therefore, is the return value from the call to `.bind`.

Answer (score 1):

This syntax is not correct:

```
exports.foo.prototype = {
  load = function(id) {
    var query = new Parse.Query("SomeObject");
    query.get(id).then(function(object) {
      this.object = object; // this is the wrong this
    });
  }
};
```

The `prototype` is an object who's properties are defined as `load: function() {}`, not `load = function() {}`.

It should be:

```
exports.foo.prototype = {
  load: function(id) {
    var query = new Parse.Query("SomeObject");
    query.get(id).then(function(object) {
      this.object = object; // this is the wrong this
    });
  }
};
```

Answer (score 0):

A simple way to do it is to declare a variable to the correct 'this' and use closuers to keep a reference to it.

```
exports.foo = function () {};

exports.foo.prototype = {
  load : function(id) {
    var self = this;

    var query = new Parse.Query("SomeObject");
    query.get(id).then(function(object) {
      self.object = object; // this is the wrong this
    });
  }
};
```